# Is this async pipelining operator ok

Tags: asynchronous, f#, pipeline

What if we define a `|>!` operator like so:

```
let (|>!) a f = async {
    let! r = a
    return f r
}
```

Then instead of writing

```
let! r = fetchAsync()
work r
```

we could write

```
fetchAsync() |>! work
```

Is this a good idea or would it generate inefficient code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `|>!` operator you're describing is the [standard "map" pattern](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-5/#extending-the-async-type-with-map-and-apply-and-bind) that can apply to just about *any* "wrapper" type, not just `async`. If your `return f r` had been `return! f r` then you would have the [standard "bind" pattern](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-bind/), which by convention should be written as the operator `>>=` if you're defining an operator for it.

And it is a good idea, but with one minor change. You've written it with the async value as the first parameter and the function as the second parameter, but the way you used it, `fetchAsync() |>! work`, requires the function to be the *first* parameter, e.g. `let (|>!) f a = ...`. (If you look at the way Scott Wlaschin implements this in the first example I linked, he puts the function as the first parameter as well.) Also, I think most F# programmers would choose not to write this as an operator, but as a function called `Async.map`, so that its usage would look like this:

```
let result =
    fetchAsync()
    |> Async.map step1
    |> Async.map step2
    |> Async.map step3
```

Comment: Async.map! Of course.  But now, it's hard to say which is better `Async.map` or `let! ...`.  Yet, I agree that `Async.map` is better than operators like `|>!`. But `|>!` is better than `let! ...`. But ...

Comment: I don't think that you can say that `|>!` is better than `let!`, because they're used in two different contexts. `let!` can only be used inside an computation expression like `async { ... }`, whereas your `|>!` operator is used *outside* a computation expression. Comparing the two is, IMHO, like saying that a bicycle is better than an umbrella: they serve different functions, and neither one can replace the function of the other one, so it doesn't really make sense to compare them.